# 4k+ privileges?

Tags: support

There have been a number of instances (questions, posts, discussions) where I see reference made to privileges granted to, e.g. 10k (view all edits to post?) and 20k rep (something mod-like). What are these, and perhaps other, privilege rights beyond the 4k? 4k seems to be the highest rep that goes with an upgrade in privileges in the "privileges" tab (i.e., trusted user)?

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of privileges and necessary reputation to earn them is given in https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/. Since we are still in beta, these are lower than those of graduated sites. See, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/.

So, while on beta sites, 4k gives access to the "Trusted User" privilege, on graduated sites, that's at 20k. That's why you've seen references to higher reputation privileges. As soon as we get out of beta, the same will apply to us as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So the  'trusted' user is as good as it possibly gets for beta?

Comment: @AliceD "Trusted user" is as good as it possible gets for all sites. What changes is the reputation threshold at which said privilege is granted.